# MySQL insert with value determined at insertion

Tags: mysql, insert

I need to set a field value, actually a flag, in a record to either 0 or 1 depending on whether the id field (int(10) auto_increment, primary key) is even or odd. I know I can determine the value after insertion with a bitwise selector and then run an update but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this within the insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to set a trigger on the insert action that will automaticaly set the parity of that field.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I guess I will have to figure out how to set triggers as I have never used them before. Any suggestions as to where I might learn more about them?

Answer (score 0):

Why use another field to store data your ID is already carrying?

Even:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (MOD(id,2) = 0)
```

Odd:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (MOD(id,2) > 0)
```

Comment: I think later he may need to change the value of the flag. So it would be better to set the flag value to NULL initially. Then use: `WHERE IFNULL(flag, MOD(id,2)) = 0`